# Function Score Query elasticsearch parsing error

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

I am trying to run a straight forward Function Score Query in elasticsearch as:

```
{
"function_score": {
  "query": {
     "term": {
        "timestamp": {
           "value": 1396361509,
           "boost": 0.05
        }
     }
  },
  "script_score": {
     "script": "abs(1396361509 - doc['timestamp'].value)"
  }
}
}
```

but I keep getting an error saying that there is no parser for "function_score":

```
 SearchParseException[[test_index][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [function_score]]]; }{[PKoYz4OLTbOWb6ziP8AIaQ][test_index][1]: SearchParseException[[test_index][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
```

I am using elasticsearch 1.1.1 and tried running it via curl call, from elastic-head, and via a JAVA API. Results are always the same!

Comment: It seems you've cut off your error message. Can you please edit the question and post the full error message.

Comment: The rest of the message just continues with the query.

Comment: SOLVED -- function score needs to be wrapped in another query. A bit strange I find!

Comment: Please write up a quick answer with your example fixed and select it as the right answer so others can easily find it

Comment: added in the main question!

Comment: @ilijaluve, I have moved your answer to the answer section.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Disclaimer: This was extracted from the question</sub>

The function score should itself be wrapped in a query! Here is an example:

```
  {
    "query": { 
      "bool" : {
        "should" : {
          "function_score" : {
                     "query" : {
          "match_all" : { }
        },
        "script_score" : {
          "script" : "_score * 1/abs(1396361509-doc['timestamp'].value)"
        }
      }
    },
    "boost" : 0.05
  }
}
```