# How to prioritize my search on text fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is how I have modeled the movie_ratings of 3 movie clubs about a particular film.

```
{

    "movie_name": "avengers,the age of ultron"
    "movie_ratings":
     {
         "canvasFilms": "average"
         "playHouse": "bad"
         "tubeRaters": "good"
         "bannersUnlimited": "excellent"
     }
}
```

Now,I want to sort the movies based on their ratings,that is my order of preference is "excellent","good","average","bad". But since it is not numbers in the fields, I'm unable to do such a sorting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it, though it's a bit of a hack:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "sort": {
      "_script": {
         "script": "if (doc[field_name].value=='excellent'){ 4 } else if (doc[field_name].value=='good'){ 3 } else if (doc[field_name].value=='average'){ 2 } else if (doc[field_name].value=='bad'){ 1 } else { 0 }",
         "type": "number",
         "params": {
            "field_name": "movie_ratings.playHouse"
         },
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
}
```

You'll have to have dynamic scripting [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24711344/2551686).

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/c47aa6f5cdb1765354f3383076954cb4d2f5505b

A better approach would be to map the ordinal rating values to numbers in another field when you're indexing, then just sort on that field.

**Edit:** Also have a look at [function scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query).