# Elasticsearch : Set the number of the elements of an array in a field

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, count

I'm trying to store the number of elements of an array into a field with an update. (updating the record with the count of the array).

Like for example

```
{
  array = [ { "a" : "b" }, { "c" : "d" } ]
  nb_elements = 2
}
```

I have tried an update with the following script

```
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.nb_elements= ctx._source.array.values.length"
}
```

But it don't work.
I also tried :

```
{
"script" : "ctx._source.nb_elements = count",
"params" : {
   "count" : ctx._source.array.values.length
   }
}
```

But i wasn't more successfull.

Does anybody know if this is possible and if, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to enable dynamic scripting by adding `script.disable_dynamic: false` to your config file.

Secondly, I'm supposing that you are using groovy ([It's the default scripting language from 1.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting)).

Using the [update api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) with this script should work:

```
{
  "script": "ctx._source.nb_elements=ctx._source.array.size"
}
```

Comment: It works , thank you. Where did you find this information ?

Comment: I've  put some links to the documentation in the answer :) I've also checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711168/elasticsearch-dynamic-scripting-disabled

Comment: Ok, for reenabling the dynamic scripting, but where did you find that i had to use size rather than count or length (i can find nothing about that).

Comment: Well, I have no idea about groovy, but I know it is a JVM language and collection classes tend to have size method in Java. So, it was a bit of intuition. If you have doubts about the language you can check its documentation: http://www.groovy-lang.org/documentation.html