# How to calculate difference between two datetime in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, datediff

I'm working with ES and I need a query that returns the difference between two datetime (`mysql timediff`), but have not found any function of ES to do that. Someone who can help me?

MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
    AVG(
      TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(r.acctstoptime,r.acctstarttime)
      )
    )
) as average_access
    
FROM radacct
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best best is scripted fields. The above search query should work , provided you have enabled dynamic scripting and these date fields are defined as date in the mapping.

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": "doc['acctstoptime'].value - doc['acctstarttime'].value"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you would be getting result in epoch , which you need to convert to your denomination.

You can read about [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html) here and some of its examples [here](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting).

Comment: It Work!!!! But I had to enable the dynamic scripting on config/elasticsearch.yml. See more in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711168/elasticsearch-dynamic-scripting-disabled) Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me... Maybe something was updated since 2015...

Answer (score 9):

Here is another example using script fields.  It converts dates to milli seconds since epoch, subtracts the two and converts the results into number of days between the two dates.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
        {
        "exists": {
            "field": "priorTransactionDate"
        }
        },
        {
        "script": {
            "script": "(doc['transactionDate'].date.millis - doc['priorTransactionDate'].date.millis)/1000/86400 < 365"
        }
        }
    ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ElasticSearch 1.4 here - in my case I need to make all numbers decimals (instead of integer) to make division work. i.e. `/1000.0/86400.0` - in case that script part didn't work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Scripted fields work, but unfortunately accepted answer doesn't work for me in 2023 with Elastic 8.10... After a lot of tries, I came with the following which works:

```
GET yourcustomindex/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "duration": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['endDate'].getValue().toEpochSecond() - doc['startDate'].getValue().toEpochSecond()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mind `toEpochSecond` in contrast with `toEpochSecond*s*` which you can also find in some answers, however it also seems outdated...