# Difference of dates in elasticsearch using kibana dev tools/any other method?

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch

I am trying to find the difference of two dates in elasticsearch, I want to know how I can do that using kibana dev tools or any other way. 
I found some ref. for this but didn't get exactly how I can do that. Any help how I can do that.

Ref. [How to calculate difference between two datetime in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658639/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-datetime-in-elasticsearch)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-script-fields

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it to another datatype and use the methods that give you the hours/mins of the date. This may be of help.
https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields

Or this post. 
[How to calculate difference between two datetime in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658639/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-datetime-in-elasticsearch)

> Your best best is scripted fields. The above search query should work , provided you have enabled dynamic scripting and these date fields are defined as date in the mapping.